# Jquery floatThead issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, import-from-excel

I convert an Excel file into an html table, I don't have `<thead></thead>` tags so I do it like that with [floatThead](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/) plugin :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 var table = $('#sheet0'); // select the table of interest
 var thead = $('<thead/>').prependTo(table); // create <thead></thead>

 table.find('tbody tr.row0').appendTo(thead);

 $('table.sheet0').floatThead({
     position: 'fixed',
     index: '8',
     overflow: 'auto'
 });
 });
```

initial "`tbody tr.row0`" html (before floatThead action ) :

```
  <thead><tr class="row0">
                <td class="column0 style47 s">Title 1</td>
                <td class="column1 style8 s">Client</td>
                <td class="column2 style8 s">Title 3</td>
                <td class="column3 style9 s">Déclarant</td>
                <td class="column4 style8 s">Date ouv.</td>
                <td class="column5 style61 s">Date</td>
                <td class="column6 style53 s">IWS</td>
                <td class="column7 style9 s">Solution</td>
                <td class="column8 style9 s">Description</td>
                <td class="column9 style8 s">Actions</td>
                <td class="column10 style58 s">Lorem</td>
                <td class="column11 style7 s">Lorem</td>
                <td class="column12 style10 s">Lorem</td>
                <td class="column13 style10 s">Lorem</td>
              </tr></thead>
```

and (I don't know why) after floatThead action :

```
<thead>
    <tr class="size-row" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 46px;">
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Title 1" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Client" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Title 3" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Déclarant" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Date ouv." style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Date" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="IWS" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Solution" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Description" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Actions" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Lorem" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Lorem" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Lorem" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Lorem" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        // HERE WHY ? i dont know //
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="" style="height: 44px;"></th>
        <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="" style="height: 44px;"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

It make blanks columns appears and change the table width...

So, how can I clone my first row properly or remove the th.floatThead-col with empty aria-label?

with nth-child ?

Thanks

Comment: ask me on floatThead github page. not enough info here to know whats busted.